# how to get site title from database in Main Layout view in codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a script that allows admin to set Site title and site email for his CMS, which gets stored in database.

I my views folder I have `_main_layout.php` file which is the basic layout of my webiste, I want to fetch that site title from database in main_layout in my nav bar.

Below is the code where I want that title:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>"><?php echo $meta_title; ?></a>
        </div>
```

The meta title here is fetched statically but I want instead `site_title` to be fetched dynamically from database.

So that admin of CMS can set the site title.

Comment: write a query to select title from database and return to your controller, pass that data to your view

Comment: $data['seo_content']=$this->your_model->get_info(); in controler and then in view check if seo_contents set then get from seo_content else get from site_title()

Comment: moreover u can write a helper function to use in all views instead of fetching it from db in all views

Comment: third way you can put it into session

Comment: @ImranQamer  yeah i think session would work, let me try

Comment: @soul  $this->data['settings'] = $this->setting_m->get(); i am fetching this index file of my settings module but i want this to be fetched in the main layout of file. it gets fetched easily in setting/index.php because its in the settings folder but how to fetch in main layout

Comment: use helper function instead which u can call from layout view directly

Comment: @ImranQamer My views Folder: admin/settings/edit& index.php files in index files i fetch the set site tile in database and in edit page i allow user to set site title these files are under admin/settings folder but the main_layout file is outside the admin folder

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry from where ever u r setting ur title its not an issue solution is you have title in your database now go to `application/helper/` create a helper file like `functions_helper.php` add it in autoload like

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','functions');
```

in helper file creat a function like

```
function get_site_title()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model("your_model");
        return $result = $CI->your_model->getSiteTitle();
    }
```

then call this function from anyfile in your project either its controller/model or view like `get_site_title()` 
and thats it

Comment: i have a helper cms helper there i wrote the code, but the issue is that it shows error where i load my model, it says undefined property. also what should i write in my view file to call that function?

Comment: also as per the code you gave me do i need to write the name of my model function instead of getSiteTitle(); ..??

Comment: you also need to load model as i have loaded in abovepath, if your model is in model/sumfolder/your.php then use $CI->load->model("sumfolder/your_model");

Comment: in view you will just write helper function name as i have written in answer but you must load helper in autoload.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_meta_title ($string)
{
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->data['meta_title'] = e($string) . ' - ' . $CI->data['meta_title'];
}
```

currently this is the way i fetch my title from cms helper
and this is done statically from admin controller  by this :
$this->data['meta_title'] = '';
in view i write echo $meta_title.

if i load the setting_m , which is my model in cms helper its shows error also i am confused how does the site title gets fetched.